# Debugging a CUP grammar

Tags: java, compiler-construction, grammar, cup

I got stuck debugging a CUP grammar.

So I have the following grammar in CUP:

```
/* Integer operators */
precedence left SUM_OP, SUBS_OP;
precedence left PROD_OP, DIV_OP;

/* Boolean operators */
precedence left EQ_OP, LT_OP, GT_OP, LET_OP, GET_OP;
precedence left OR_OP;
precedence left AND_OP;

start with statements;

statements ::= statement:s 
             | statement:s SEPARATOR
             | SEPARATOR // Empty statement
             | statement:s SEPARATOR statements:ss 
             ;

statement  ::= IF expression:e SEPARATOR statement:s
             | IF expression:e statement:s
             | IF expression:e SEPARATOR then_statement:then ELSE SEPARATOR statement:els 
             | IF expression:e then_statement:then ELSE SEPARATOR statement:els 
             | IF expression:e SEPARATOR then_statement:then ELSE statement:els 
             | IF expression:e then_statement:then ELSE statement:els 
             | WHILE expression:e SEPARATOR statement:s
             | WHILE expression:e statement:s
             | non_if_statement:s
             ;

then_statement ::= IF expression:e SEPARATOR then_statement:then ELSE SEPARATOR then_statement:els 
                   | IF expression:e then_statement:then ELSE SEPARATOR then_statement:els 
                   | IF expression:e SEPARATOR then_statement:then ELSE then_statement:els 
                   | IF expression:e then_statement:then ELSE then_statement:els 
                   | WHILE expression:e SEPARATOR then_statement:s
                   | WHILE expression:e then_statement:s
                   | non_if_statement:s
                   ;

non_if_statement ::= START_BLOCK statements:s END_BLOCK
                   | declaration:d
                   | assignment:a
                   ;

// The statement vs then_statement is for disambiguation purposes
// Solution taken from http://goldparser.org/doc/grammars/example-if-then-else.htm

/* Variable manipulation statements */
declaration ::= type:t IDENTIFIER:id 
              | type:t IDENTIFIER:id ASSIGN_OP expression:rhs 
              ;

assignment  ::= variable:lhs ASSIGN_OP expression:rhs
              ;

/* Variable manipulation auxiliar sintactic elements */
type       ::= T_INT 
             | T_BOOL 
             | type:t T_ARRAY 
             ;

variable   ::= IDENTIFIER:id 
             | variable:id LBRACKET expression:idx RBRACKET
             ;

/* Integer or bool expressions */
expression ::= variable:v 
             | LPAREN expression:e RPAREN

          // Int expressions
             |  INTEGER_LITERAL:c 
             | expression:op1 SUM_OP expression:op2 
             | expression:op1 SUBS_OP expression:op2 
             | expression:op1 PROD_OP expression:op2 
             | expression:op1 DIV_OP expression:op2 

           // Bool expressions
             | BOOL_LITERAL:c
             | expression:op1 OR_OP expression:op2 
             | expression:op1 AND_OP expression:op2 
             | NOT_OP expression:op1 
             | expression:op1 EQ_OP expression:op2 
             | expression:op1 LT_OP expression:op2 
             | expression:op1 GT_OP expression:op2 
             | expression:op1 LET_OP expression:op2 
             | expression:op1 GET_OP expression:op2 
             ;
```

The lexer is feeding the following tokens to the CUP analyzer:

```
 int id:i = intLiteral ;    
 { 
     if id:i == intLiteral id:i = intLiteral ;
 } 


 while id:i < intLiteral ;
 { 
     id:i = id:i + intLiteral ;
 } 
 if id:i <= intLiteral ;    
 { 
     bool id:a ;

     bool id:b = boolLiteral ;
 } 
 else ;
 { 
     int id:j = intLiteral ;
 } 
 if id:i >= intLiteral ;
 { 
     id:i = id:i - intLiteral ;
     { 
         id:i = intLiteral + intLiteral ;

     } 
 } 
 else if id:i > intLiteral id:i = intLiteral ;

 else id:i = intLiteral
```

(Where `;` is `SEPARATOR` and `{ }` deliminate the blocks.

When I run it, I get the following output:

```
 int 
 id:i
type ::= T_INT
 = 
 intLiteral 
 ;

expression ::= INTEGER_LITERAL
declaration ::= type IDENTIFIER ASSIGN_OP expression
non_if_statement ::= declaration
statement ::= non_if_statement
 { 
 if 
 id:i
 == 
variable ::= IDENTIFIER
expression ::= variable
 intLiteral 
 id:i
expression ::= INTEGER_LITERAL
expression ::= expression EQ_OP expression
 = 
variable ::= IDENTIFIER
 intLiteral 
 ;

expression ::= INTEGER_LITERAL
assignment ::= variable ASSIGN_OP expression
non_if_statement ::= assignment
statement ::= non_if_statement
statement ::= IF expression statement
 } 
statements ::= statement SEPARATOR
 while 
Error in line 7, column 1 : Syntax error
Error in line 7, column 1 : Couldn't repair and continue parse
```

(lines with a single word represent a call to the lexer that resulted in the token printed. Lines with a CUP rule represent that rule being matched. Line 7 is the one with the while statement on it.)

It seems like the blocks are the reason for the failure; when I remove all the blocks from what is fed to the grammar everything is parsed as I expect.

However, I fail to see why the blocks are not correctly parsed.

Any ideas on what could be the problem or how to test further?

EDIT: In case you need a detail I might have ommitted to answer, the full code is available in [this repo](https://github.com/Jsevillamol/serum)

Comment: Doesn't CUP complain about the shift-reduce conflicts? Where are your precedence declarations?

Comment: @rici apologies, I ommitted those to make the question more readable. I will add them for completition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way your grammar uses semi-colons is a bit unorthodox. And it's getting you into trouble.

In particular, semi-colons seem to be optional everywhere except between statements. So both of these are OK

```
while i < 3; i = i + 1;   // ex. 1
while i < 3 i = i + 1;    // ex. 2
```

but you cannot write

```
 i = 2 j = 3              // ex. 3
```

even though that is no more or less ambiguous than ex. 2 above.

The semicolon-less syntaxes look less strange with blocks:

```
while i < 3;  { i = i + 1;  } // ex. 4
while i < 3 { i = i + 1;  }  // ex. 5
{ i = 2 } { j = 3 }            // ex. 6 Still illegal
```

In order to be parsed, example 6 would need to be written with a semi-colon which is, to my eye, ugly and unnecessary:

```
{ i = 2 } ; { j = 3 }            // ex. 7
```

That's what your parser is complaining about. Even though the statement on lines 2-4 is a brace-enclosed, so there's never any doubt about where it ends, your grammar insists on a semicolon. But the next token is `while`, not a semicolon, which is a syntax error.

Comment: Thank you! Any suggestion on how to modify the grammar so that the semicolon in ex 6 is no longer needed?

Comment: Actually, I can just forget about using semicolons, and this seems to work alright. Problem solved!